# Adding list under <SelectInput> field

Tags: react-admin

I need to add a dropdown list under the purpose, I have added under choices inside the selectInput field.
The list is displaying, but when I click on save button its showing purpose must be a string.

```
            <SimpleForm>
                <SelectInput label="Purpose" source="purpose" choices={[
                    { id: 1, name: "Diagnosis" },
                    { id: 2, name: "Surgery" },
                    { id: 3, name: "Chemotherapy" },
                    { id: 4, name: 'Concurrent (Chemo+Radiation)' },
                    { id: 5, name: 'Concurrent Followup(Chemo+Radiation)'},
                    { id: 6, name: 'Palliative Treatment' },
                    { id: 7, name: 'Post-Chemotherapy Follow up' },
                    { id: 8, name: 'Post-Radiation Follow up' },
                    { id: 9, name: 'Post-Surgery Follow up' },
                    { id: 10, name: 'Radiation' },
                    { id: 11, name: 'Side effect/ Supportive Care' }
                ]} />
                <SelectInput label="Hospitals" source="hospital_id" choices={hospitalsArr} required />
                <SelectInput label="Patients" source="patient_id" choices={patientsArr} required />
                <DateInput source="appointment_date" onChange={this.handleOnchange} />
                <SelectInput label="Slots" source="appointment_id" choices={slotsInputArr} required />
            </SimpleForm>
        </Create>
```

Comment: I didn't understand the issue. When you save your value, it doesn't show it?
Or you want to save the value as a string in your data provider?

Comment: The dropdown list is displaying and when I click on the save button it is showing as purpose must be a string.so, I want to save the value as a string.